# Automatic USB boot up and persistence fil

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

Two issues: (1) cannot get Ubuntu to automatically boot from memory stick (nor am I offered a choice of OS to run in BIOS menu); 2) Cannot save changes/additions to Ubuntu persistence file. Working on HP desktop w/ Windows 7

Comment: Please read the FAQ.  Questions are expected to be in the form of... a question, and should have a meaningful subject.

Answer (score 1):

the first is typically set in your BIOS somewhere.

Second, how did you set up your persistence ? Here is how I do it.

Mount your usb device, and cd to the root of the device. Assuming it is mounted at `/media/Live`

```
cd /media/Live

# this will make a 1 Gb file for storage
# increase / decrease the count as needed
dd if=/dev/zero of=./home-rw bs=1M count=1000

# Make a file system.
mkfs.ext4 home-rw

mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
home-rw is not a block special device.

# Answer ‘yes’ here
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y

#Remove the reserved blocks
tune2fs -m 0 -L home-rw home-rw
```

When you boot, you need to add the boot option `persistent` to the options.

**NOTE** the file nema `home-rw` is for a persistent /home directory only (IMO it works better). If you want a persistent / directory, change the name from home-rw to `casper-rw`. Take care with a persistent /, I would not advise you install or upgrade a bunch of packages, it takes a lot of space and is not always reliable, IMO better to remaster the live CD.

See

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence#Booting_the_Live_CD_in_Persistent_Mode

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization